# Excel VBA SUMIF across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am writing a function to sum flight hours of each day for 1 entire month.

I have tried 2 scenarios - returning a string that would populate the cell with a formula.
Attempt to return the value for the cell. The second I suppose is preferred.
The Function should should return either var or string.
All my attempts have thrown errors on the line assigning the return value.

```
Option Explicit

  Function HoursFlown() As String
  'writes formula for cells d10:d14 to calculate hours flown
  'checks across all worksheets (each day of month) confirms pilot
  'and a flight exists and sums "flight hours totals" for toatal hours in month to date.
  '!!!At present this is not a function so does not return a result and takes no arguments.
     Application.Volatile
     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer
     Dim strTabs As String

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 2 To WS_Count

        ' Insert your code here.
        'strTabs = strTabs & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name
        strTabs = strTabs & "(SUMIF('" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name & "'!L3:L4,c10,'" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name & "'!M3:M4)+"

        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        'MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name
        'MsgBox strTabs

     Next I

        strTabs = "=" & (Left(strTabs, Len(strTabs) - 1)) & "))"
        'Range("J19").Formula = MsgBox(strTabs)  '<-- this is working (it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't return the correct results)
        'Range("J19").Value = strTabs
        'Range("J20").Formula = strTabs 'this line throws object-defined error
        HoursFlown = strTabs
  End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Application.SumIf instead...

```
  Function HoursFlown() As Double
  'writes formula for cells d10:d14 to calculate hours flown
  'checks across all worksheets (each day of month) confirms pilot
  'and a flight exists and sums "flight hours totals" for toatal hours in month to date.
  '!!!At present this is not a function so does not return a result and takes no arguments.
     Application.Volatile
     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer
     Dim total As Double

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     total = 0
     For I = 2 To WS_Count

        total = total + Application.SumIf(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("L3:L4"), Range("c10").Value, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("M3:M4"))

     Next I

     HoursFlown = total

  End Function
```

**EDIT**

For the IntelliSense, you can refer to the SumIf member of the WorksheetFunction object (ie. WorksheetFunction.SumIf(...)).  However, in this case, if it returns an error, you'll get a breaking error, for which you'll need to handle.

With Application.SumIf, though, if an error is returned, you'll get a ***non-breaking*** error, for which you can test using the IsError function...

```
Dim total as Variant 'declared as Variant in case SumIf returns an error

total = Application.SumIf(.....)

If Not IsError(total) Then
    'do something
Else
    'do something else
End If
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You, this is certainly getting me in the right direction.  But I have a quandary that perhaps you can shed light on.  I tried Application.SumIf previously and from what I can find it "does not exist".  Intellisense does not recognize it and microsoft-docs does not list it.  So I never actually tried it... Since it did not appear to exist.